# PostgreSQL 9.4.7: PostGIS 2.2.1 via Stackbuilder Checksum issue

Tags: postgresql, installation, postgis-2.2, stackbuilder, checksum

When installing PostGIS via Stackbuilder (3.1.1) I get an error:

**"checksum verification failed for: postgis_2_2_pg94.exe! deleting file..."**

I've neither seen this in previous installations nor found constructive solutions in the internet.

Download and installation of postgis-bundle-pg94x32-setup-2.2.1-1.exe seemed at first to work properly, but I was not able to add the postgis-extension to my DB. The error was something like

**"could not load programs(x86)\PostgreSQL\9.4\lib\rtpostgis-2.2.dll"**

But for shure this file is where it belongs and is expected.

Platform is Win10, MS Surface3 based on Intel Atom.

What might have gone wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause for this must have been an unstable internet connection (hotspot via Smartphone). One should not try to install various things from the internet (eg. OSGeo4w etc.) at the same time over a weak internet connection. Patience is required here!

Second issue went away with reboot and reconnect to the PostgreSQL Database Server. No big deal at all.